# Passing DateTime variable to controller causing an error

Tags: json, json.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am building a small prediction feature into my application. Running into an issue which I cannot seem to understand. I am calculating some basic results and returning a Dictionary containing the 2 results. Thought this would be a good way to get back both results from one function instead of calling two. I have found some proposed solutions for this error such as converting the DateTime to a string but this did not work for me either. Would appreciate any insight into the cause of the error. Thanks in advance.

### Error

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
    System.Text.Json.JsonException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
     ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
       at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
       at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
       at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
       at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
       at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
       at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
       at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
       at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[Dictionary`2](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
       at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[Dictionary`2](JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, JsonConverter converterBase)
       at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.<ReadAsync>d__20`1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
       at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__3`1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
       at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__9`1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
       at WebApp.Client.Pages.Prediction.Predict.InitPrediction() in C:\Users\source\repos\WebApp\WebApp\Client\Pages\Prediction\Predict.razor:line 48
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

This error only started to occur when I started passing a DateTime variable when making the Get request

### Razor page: problematic

```
[CascadingParameter]
private DateTime selectedDate { get; set; } = new DateTime();
private Dictionary<string, int> predictedInfo = new Dictionary<string, int>();

 private async Task InitPrediction()
    {
        predictedInfo = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, int>>($"Prediction/{selectedDate}");
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/prediction");
    }
```

### Controller: problematic

```
[HttpGet("{date}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Dictionary<string, int>>> GetProjects(DateTime date)
{

  int total_projects_per_company = 0;
  int users_per_project_sum = 0;

  Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// calculation code...


  d.Add("users", users_per_project_sum);
  d.Add("projects", total_projects_per_company);
  return d;
}
```

The problem does not occur when **I do not pass the DateTime** and I am not sure what the correlation between this is.

### Razor page: Not causing a problem

```
[CascadingParameter]
private DateTime selectedDate { get; set; } = new DateTime();
private Dictionary<string, int> predictedInfo = new Dictionary<string, int>();

private async Task InitPrediction()
{
  predictedInfo = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, int>>("Prediction");
  Navigation.NavigateTo("/prediction");
}
```

### Controller: Not causing a problem

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<Dictionary<string, int>>> GetProjects()
{
  int total_projects_per_company = 0;
  int users_per_project_sum = 0;

  Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
 // calculation code...
  d.Add("users", users_per_project_sum);
  d.Add("projects", total_projects_per_company);
  return d;
}
```

Comment: The error indicates that quite probably HTML is being returned instead of JSON (almost certainly one of the default error pages).  Probably there's some error happening on the server that is resulting in an error page.

Comment: *`'<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.`* means that the `<`character  was encountered as the first character of the JSON stream.  This usually indicating that the JSON was actually HTML or XML as mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure what would be causing an error on the server. All I have done differently is introduced DateTime into the controller function. Quite confused with this one

Comment: The application never manages to call the function at the controller. It hits the line  `predictedInfo = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, int>>($"Prediction/{selectedDate}");` and throws the error and stops. The function at the controller is never used or called by the application

Comment: @Krellex, use your browser's dev tools to examine the response from the server.  Since I expect it to contain an error message, it ought to be sufficient for you to diagnose your issue.